# Comparison of two measurement methods - determining measurement reliability

Tags: reliability, method-comparison

The aim is to compare two measurement methods. Therefore with each method two consecutive measurements were performed on 25 subjects (so overall 4 x 25 measured values) The relevant parameter is an amplitude.

To determine the reliability of each method, the “interindividual coefficient of variation” and the ”re-test coefficient of variation” should be calculated. I don’t really understand the difference and what is expressed by these two coefficients?

Does it make sense to calculate the “Intraclass correlation coefficient” (ICC, two way mixed)? Is it the same as the “re-test-Coefficient of variation”?

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear who or what you are quoting, but it seems that they want estimates of what are often referred to as "inter-rater reliability" and "intra-rater reliability." Inter-rater reliability quantifies the consistency of measurements across the two methods, while intra-rater reliability quantifies the consistency of measurements within each method. You are correct that calculating an ICC makes sense here. Which formulation of the ICC you pick will be determined by characteristics of the data that you haven't shared yet.